# Google Tag Manager for iOS AdWords Conversion Tracking Error

Tags: ios, google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

GTM SDK Version: 3.09
Platform: iOS
Tag: AdWords Conversion tracking

When trying to fire an AdWords conversion tracking tag via Google Tag Manager for apps, I'm seeing the following messages (only relevant messages shown):

```
_aid has no backing implementation.
Dispatch url: http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1234567/?gclid=&appversion=3.1.a&conv=1234567&label=abc&ai=&timestamp=1413203719&osversion=8.0.2&bundleid=com.example&lat=0&idtype=idfa&sdkversion=gtm-i-v3.0&rdid=1234&remarketing_only=0
Successfully sent hit: http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1234567/?gclid=&appversion=3.1.a&conv=1234567&label=abc&ai=&timestamp=1413203719&osversion=8.0.2&bundleid=com.example&lat=0&idtype=idfa&sdkversion=gtm-i-v3.0&rdid=1234&remarketing_only=0
```

I suspect the _aid error is related to the inability to access the IDFA. I have included all the libraries and frameworks stated here (https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v3/#add-sdk) and I have used the force_load flag as well, but I'm still getting this error message.

As for the dispatch URL, we can again see that the ai query parameter (which I assume should equal the IDFA), is left blank. I'm not sure how the hit is able to be "sucessfully sent" despite the ai parameter missing. The status of the conversion in the AdWords interface remains as "unverified".

Any idea how I can get rid of the `_aid has no backing implementation` error message and properly get the `ai` parameter to populate?